# Set a selection as a saved Range

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do with this is:

1. Search for "Part Class". I'm doing this because it can be in different spots on different sheets.
2. Save the column address as "a" which is set as a Range
3. Search through that column for each of the 5 criteria and delete those entire rows.

When I run this code, I get an "object required" error.

```
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim NSC As String

Cells.Find("Part Class").Activate
Set a = Selection.EntireColumn.Select   'Here is where the issue comes from
a.Find("CONS").EntireRow.DELETE
a.Find("MISC").EntireRow.DELETE
a.Find("PFG").EntireRow.DELETE
a.Find("PRT").EntireRow.DELETE
a.Find("TOTE").EntireRow.DELETE
```

The answer may be simple, but I have little knowledge of VBA language. I feel like my issue is with my syntax and/or how I'm trying to continue with the "Part Class" search.

**FOLLOW UP PROBLEM:**

Okay so I took Tim's code and edited a little but now I'm getting an issue of "sub or function not defined". Would that be because of the Label I made?

```
Dim a As Range
Dim loopCount As Integer

Dim NSC As String

Set a = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Part Class").EntireColumn

On Error Resume Next
Do While loopCount > 0
    a.Find("CONS").EntireRow.DELETE
    a.Find("MISC").EntireRow.DELETE
    a.Find("PFG").EntireRow.DELETE
    a.Find("PRT").EntireRow.DELETE
    a.Find("TOTE").EntireRow.DELETE
    On Error GoTo Break1
Loop

Label Break1
```

I wanted to do something like loopCount++ but I'm not sure how to put that in there.

Comment: `Label` isn't a keyword in VBA

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As Range

Set a = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Part Class")

If a Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set a = a.EntireColumn

'Note: if any of the terms below are not found then you'll get
'  a run-time error
'If you want to ignore those then uncomment the lines noted

'On Error Resume Next '<<##
With a
    .Find("CONS").EntireRow.DELETE
    .Find("MISC").EntireRow.DELETE
    .Find("PFG").EntireRow.DELETE
    .Find("PRT").EntireRow.DELETE
    .Find("TOTE").EntireRow.DELETE
End With
'On Error Goto 0 '<<##
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thank you very much.  What does this line mean:  'On Error Goto 0 '<<##

Comment: That line clears the `On Error Resume Next` - basically it means in this context "stop ignoring errors"

Comment: Okay so the loopCount idea is taking a while and I know it should be cleaner.  What's the cleanest way to loop your Find block to run until nothing is found?